# While setting up release pipeline azure subscription error

Tags: azure-devops

My account and subscription is active in portal.azure.com and also same account I have been using for azure devops as well, However while trying to add new service connection in release pipeline section I am seeing below error. Please help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BedEM.png)

Comment: Microsoft Azure owners ... Please fix this bug, I am getting this as well as tons of others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow these steps to troubleshoot the error "You don’t appear to have an active Azure subscription".

1. Open a new InPrivate/incognito window of browser, and try to create a service connection again.
2. Go to https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Billing/SubscriptionsBlade to check if your subscription status is active.
3. Go to https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/TenantPropertiesBlade to check whether the Security defaults is disabled.

In addition, when the user is assigned the subscription for the first time, it needs time to sync the changes when logging in to Azure DevOps.

If there is still the error, please report your issue to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem), you could share your detailed messages in private channel (Microsoft Only).

Comment: HI Parmela Peng, From the solution you have provided 3rd solution worked. Thank you.

Comment: Open a new InPrivate/incognito is solve the issue, Thanks